# can i access latest blocks data with geth --fast --rpc?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

Geth full node is consuming too much of hard disk space. If i don't use full node and use `geth --fast` then will I able to get latest blocks data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have an access to the latest `1024 blocks` like in a **Full** sync.

Comment: and if i use light sync then also i will be able to access latest blocks data ?

Comment: @Farhan no. Light sync gives you access only to current state without any historic data.